# data not loading while redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, flask, redirect

```
def records():
    return render_template('records.html')

@app.route('/record_data', methods=["GET"])
def record_data():
    data = [{"Name": "Test1", "Address": "Address1"},{"Name": "Test2", "Address": "Address2"}]
    jdata = json.dumps(data)
    print(jdata)
return jdata
```

Js file:

```
     $("#table tr").click(function() {
         window.location.assign("record");
      });

      });
      }
    if ("RecordPage" === title)
    {
        var $tablerecords = $('#tablerecords');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: "record_data"
            }).done(function(records){
                var rd_list = JSON.parse(records);
                var table_rd_html="";
                for (const rd in rd_list) {
                    if (rd_list.hasOwnProperty(rd)) {
                    table_rd_html += "<tr>";
                    table_rd_html += "<td>" + rd_list[rd]["Name"] + "</td>";
                    table_rd_html += "<td>" + rd_list[rd]["Address"] + "</td>";
                    table_rd_html += "</tr>";
                   }
                }
                $("tablerecords").children("tbody").html(table_rd_Html);
                let content = document.getElementById('tablerecords');
                let children = content.childNodes;
                alert(children);
            });
    }
```

Im able to redirect to another url '/record' but the data is not loading on the redirected page